# Recommended JS library for origami-like paper folding animation

Tags: canvas, webgl, three.js

I would like to create an origami-like paper folding animation using WebGL or Canvas (no Flash!).
The effect I would like to reproduce is similar to the one in the [video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0TuPsNJ-XY).

A clear view of the final animation could be represented as follows for a cube:

[image]

I was trying to use [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) library, but I couldn't find a way to animate a single face of a THREE.Mesh. I also tried simple CSS3 animation, but it would make very difficult to animate solid with more than 6 faces - as it is not possibile to create relationships between 2 or more faces.

Anyone can recommend other JS libraries? Or is there a way to achieve this with three.js?
Of course, it would be great if there could be a way to make it work just using canvas2d - but I think is pretty unlikely!

Comment: Just a thought -- So it sounds like you're creating a cube and want to animate the faces. What if you create 6 rectangular prisms (just 6 cubes with 0 or near 0 thickness) and animate each face as a separate object? Perhaps then you can abstract the process to work for 3-d shapes with N faces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which framework is best, but I think it's best to use a framework that supports skinned meshes and animation playback. A quick search gave...

http://www.oak3d.com/

...but I have no idea if it's the way to go. Three have (or at least had) support for skinning but to get the data out of a 3D-program wasn't trivial and animation playback was/is limited.

Comment: yes it could work...as soon as I can make a working demo I will post it here...still it would be better to implement the animation native in JS without using a 3D program first...

Comment: You're most probably able to grab the bones of a skinned mesh and do the animation in JS.

Comment: And now it's a Japanese cemetery website

Comment: And now it's a Chinese Rubber Exchange Market

Comment: And now it's a swiss visualization company

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend http://oridomi.com/ as an inspiration. It offers basic folding animations.

Answer (score -1):

if you use Maya as 3D-program then try www.inka3d.com. then you can animate it in maya simply by parenting the top face to the front face and all side faces to the floor (each being a plane object), and crating some keyframes. then add a camera, do "export all..." and you're done